# Mysql Export Table with Column Headers to file tab delimited

Tags: mysql

I am trying to export one row MySQL table with headers to a file.  The column names and the data don't line up, and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Here's my query:

```
(Select 'LastName','FirstName','Title')  
UNION ALL (SELECT   LastName, FirstName,Title 
INTO OUTFILE '/var/tmp /outfile'  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t\t' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' FROM people_table LIMIT 1)
```

And here's the output:

```
Last Name    FirstName    Title 
Smith    Chuck    Mr.
```

Answer (score 0):

The tab stop is 8 chars wide, but your column name is longer than 8 chars while the first value isn't, so they end at different tab stops.

To get the text aligned, you could use [`RPAD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_rpad) to make each string the same width, with spaces added as padding.